# Comment s'appelle ce truc qui permet de sortir les cornichons du bocal?

Tags: vocabulaire

Comment s'appelle ce truc qui permet de sortir les cornichons du bocal (sans y plonger les doigts) et eventuellement de les égoutter ?

Je parle de ce truc là:
[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Le [net](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/puisette) semble indiquer que le terme correct est **puisette**.

Amora [a inventé](https://invention-europe.com/2017/05/25/voici-comment-impressionner-les-americains/) le **tire-croq**.

Et la [dÉsencyclopédie](https://desencyclopedie.org/wiki/Le_truc_en_plastique_dont_on_ne_se_souvient_jamais_du_nom_qui_sert_%C3%A0_sortir_les_cornichons_du_bocal_sans_y_mettre_les_doigts) parle de **truc en plastique dont on ne se souvient jamais du nom qui sert à sortir les cornichons du bocal sans y mettre les doigts**
:)

Answer (score 7):

Je dirais que ce truc est un genre d'épuisette. Une épuisette est un instrument de pêche « comprenant un manche et un filet tenu ouvert par une boucle, et utilisé pour attraper des poissons ou autres organismes pour les sortir de l'eau », selon [Wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89puisette).

Épuisette à pêche : 
[image: Épuisette à pêche]

On utilise également ce terme pour l'outil de piscine : 
[image: outil de piscine]

Et on l'utilise également pour l’ustensile à fondue : 
[image: ustensile à fondue]

Le terme a déjà été utilisé pour des instruments sans relation à la pêche, alors j'opterais pour « épuisette ».

Answer (score 3):

J'ai trouvé sur [google/image](http://www.google.fr/search?q=ascenseur%20%C3%A0%20cornichon&hl=fr&prmd=imvns&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X) en cherchant « ascenceur à cornichon » la même image.

Mais j'aime beaucoup la définition de la désencyclopédie…

Comment: Ascenceur ? On est pas loin du *monte-courge*...